# Android ArcGIS map loading progress

Tags: android, dictionary, loading, arcgis

I am currently working on a Android project that uses arcGIS maps. I've been searching the web for a way to show the loading progress of the map whenever the maps needs to load. I know that this functionality is present in Silverlight and Javascript's API and I'd like to know if this is possible in Android too. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it yourself．

first you add a setOnStatusChangedListener to a map/layer. 
you start a progress dialog when the map/layer is starting charging, and you close the progress dialog when map/layer is load by check OnStatusChangedListener.STATUS.LAYER_LOADED